# Using "make all" results in Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, elf

I have a C project that I am trying to compile using a Makefile. The project has worked for me before on other machines. However, on this particular one, I keep on getting this error sequence:

Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)

error adding symbols: File in wrong format

I believe this may be related to the object linker that is on my machine, but I'm not sure how to go about fixing it. I tried re-installing gcc, but that had no effect either.

Comment: maybe you need `-fPIC` option to force relocatable code?

Comment: You need to provide _a lot_ more info for anyone to help you. What command is actually failing? What is the _exact_ error message?

Comment: It's more likely an issue with the libraries installed on the build machine than with the toolchain.  But we really don't have nearly enough information to say anything specific.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.